# Memory management of function pointers and lambdas

Tags: c++, memory-management, lambda, function-pointers

I'm relatively new in C++, and I've some questions about memory management.

I'm a C# developer and memory management is easier than C++ because of the garbage collector and I don't know when I've to free memory manually.

For example:

```
void (*ptr)() = [] { /* 1rst lambda expression code*/ };
ptr = [] { /*2nd lambda expression code*/ };
```

What happen with the first lambda expression?, Is still in memory?, I've to do something before reassigning 'ptr'?.

If someone can explain to me this particular case and how C++ and memory works I would appreciate it!.

Comment: The only time you need to free memory yourself is when you allocate it dynamically yourself, via the `new` operator, a `malloc()`-like function, a direct OS memory function, etc (or you are making a library call that does such an allocation for you). That allocated memory has to be freed using the corresponding release function. Any other time, memory management is handled automatically for you. Since your lambda is not being allocated dynamically, there is nothing for you to free. Just because you have a pointer to something doesn't always mean you have to free what is being pointing at

Answer (score 2):

The C++ language handles lambda functions without capture lists as though they were real functions with some compiler-generated name that's different from the names of all other functions. As a result, when you write

```
void (*ptr)() = [] { /* 1rst lambda expression code*/ };
```

it's kinda sorta like writing the following:

```
static void _CompilerGeneratedFn137() {
    /* lambda code */
}

void (*ptr)() = &_CompilerGeneratedFn137;
```

No memory is actually allocated here (except for the space for the `ptr` variable itself), and the pointer just points somewhere into the code segment of the program. When you then reassign `ptr` to point to a different lambda, you're not leaking any memory; you're just changing which anonymous function the `ptr` variable points at.

Hope this helps!